# Why can I directly subtract two Date objects?

Tags: javascript

I always wondered. Clearly, if I do

```
const a = new Date();
```

, a will hold the reference to an instance of Date. It has methods, etc. Why is it, then, that I can subtract two dates using simple the - operator in between?

```
const a = new Date();
const b = new Date();
console.log(a - b);
```

Am I not subtracting two objects here? Does Date "extend" Number in some way? And, can I, for myself, define what those operators do for my own classes, similarly to how C# does it with operator overloading?

Comment: `-` uses `valueOf`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf - see https://jsfiddle.net/2449foaL/1/

Comment: @Caramiriel Oh. How could I have missed that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

It does not apply only to `Date` objects. You can make use of `valueOf` in your objects as well.

```js
const a = {}
a.valueOf = () => 100
console.log(a + 1) // 101
```

Answer (score -1):

Difference between two dates, in milliseconds

```js
const a = new Date();
console.log( a.getTime() ); // 1527942328972
console.log( Math.abs( a ) ); // 1527942328972

const b = new Date( "2018/02/01" );
const diff = Math.abs( a - b );
const diff1 = a.getTime() - b.getTime();

console.log( diff ); // 10509974822
console.log( diff1 ); // 10509974822
```

Comment: @DavidsKanal because Math.abs returns the absolute value of a number (but in first it converts them before calculating result)

Answer (score -3):

You can get the difference in milliseconds.

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
var diff = Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime());
console.log(diff);
```

You can get the difference of the days from two dates.

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date( "2018/5/01" );
var timeDiff = Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays);
```